# button redirects you to another page in Android studio Java

Tags: java, android

if you guys know how to do that share it with me I would appreciate your help ! Thanks for reading

Comment: Have you tried to do it yourself?

Comment: Check this tutorial out https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: No, I haven't tried Im beginner at android studio I started this week ! Im ignoring xml and learning more Java

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
in the help documentation, and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic 
 Remember to include Minimal, complete, verifiable examples:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Then, click `edit` to edit your question so that we may help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a method that is called when the button is pressed (make sure that your button's onclick method is set to this).
2. Create your new page.
3. In the button pressed method create an intent (this represents the apps intent to do something). Make this intent start your new activity (page).

The above is outlined really well in this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) I would advise you follow this tutorial if you are new to android development, it is really clear 
 and easy to follow along.

Answer (score 0):

1º - Right button on your package -> New -> Activity -> Empty Activity -> Put a name as ScreenTwoActivity -> Finish

2º - In your activity_main.xml, create a button, and add the property onClick with a value, for example: onClick="nextPage"

3º - In MainActivity, create a method like:

```
    public void nextPage(View view){
       startActivity(new Intent(this, ScreenTwoActivity.class));
    }
```

4º - Be happy

Comment: Thanks man you just made my night ! Appreciate your help :] Now I can code my first simple app

Comment: You're welcome man :)